# my code doesn't work with two setintervals

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I want my code to grab a certain time using moment.js, correlate that to a "frame" number and then use that to populate a url to get a specified image in a sequence. That url will then iterate through a sequence of image urls at a rate of 500ms (they are small images, like 20k). I do that with my setInterval function called getframe.

But to make sure my frame iterator doesn't get too far behind by lag I also want to run another setinterval called gettime that updates the frame variable based on a fresh moment.js timestamp. I have this running every 10000ms. Problem is my code doesn't work with these two setIntervals running at the same time. If I take function gettime out of a setinterval it works fine but when I put it back in it stops and I can't figure out why?

Open to suggestions about how to do this gettime update more efficiently but I'm pretty limited when it comes to my jquery skills (sorry) so you'll have to be very detailed in your explanation of why/how something would work..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="three/js/moment.js"> </script>
    <script src="three/js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  <style>
  .frames { position:relative; width:500px; height:332px; }
  .frames img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
  </style>
  <head>

  <body>

<img id ="frame_placeholder">

<script>





  window.onload = $(function (){

    setInterval(gettime,10000);

    setInterval(getframe,500); 

    function gettime(){
      now = moment().zone('-0500')

      if (now.hour() >= 18) {
      now = now.subtract('hour', 18).subtract('minute', 30)
      } else {
      now = now.add('hour', 6).add('minute', 30)
        };

    var frame = ((now.hour() * 3600) + (now.minute() * 60) + now.second()) * 2;


    };


    function getframe(){
      var framestr=frame.toString();
                            function pad (str, max) 
                            {
                              return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
                            }; 

      framerun = pad (framestr,5);

      var src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/image"+ framerun +".jpg"

      framerun1=parseInt(framerun)
      $("#frame_placeholder").attr("src", src);
      frame=framerun1+=1;

    }

  });






</script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what does your console say? any errors thrown? Does gettime run by itself (without getframe)?

Comment: frame is not defined inside getframe()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/kMn4N/)***

The scope of your variables is to blame here. `frame` is scoped locally to `gettime` and so when it is used in `getframe` frame is undefined and there is an error. This can be fixed by placing the frame variable inside of the onload function but outside of gettime, by removing the `var` from `gettime` for frame, and by placing an undefined check in `getframe`.

```
setInterval(gettime,10000);
setInterval(getframe,500); 

var frame;

function gettime(){
 now = moment().zone('-0500');

 if (now.hour() >= 18) {
  now = now.subtract('hour', 18).subtract('minute', 30);
 } else {
  now = now.add('hour', 6).add('minute', 30);
 }
 frame = ((now.hour() * 3600) + (now.minute() * 60) + now.second()) * 2;
}
function getframe(){
 var framestr = frame? frame.toString() : "";
 function pad (str, max){
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
 }
 framerun = pad (framestr,5);
 var src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/image"+ framerun +".jpg";
 framerun1=parseInt(framerun);
 $("#frame_placeholder").attr("src", src);
 frame=framerun1+=1;
}
```

Comment: awesome! this seems to be the right track-- the problem now seems to be that gettime waits to run for ~10 secs upon loading (don't know if this is because it waits one interval to run or what?) and so for that period the frame isn't being defined by the timestamp of gettime properly

Comment: maybe i could put gettime in before 'onload', is there some jscript command that will give gettime priority over getframe?

Comment: @user3079080 - To run it right away, just place a call to it at the end of your onload function. `gettime();`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your direct question, but if you are trying to animate something to change every half-second, you might want to preload your images using the Javascript `Image` object:

```
var frames = [];
var loadCount = 0;
function preloadImages() {
  for (var i = 0; i < TOTAL_FRAMES; i++) {
    loadFrame("myurl" + i + ".jpg", i);
  }
}

function loadFrame(url, frameNumber) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  img.onload(function() {
    frames[frameNumber] = img;
    loadCount++;
    if (loadCount == TOTAL_FRAMES) {
      startAnimation();
    }
  });
}
```

Basically, this loops through all of your image URLs, downloads them and stores them in an array, then runs a callback after each one. If all images have been downloaded, your animation starts and you don't have to worry about loading images from your server. Also, your frames are organized in an array that you can simply loop through them when you run the animation.

Comment: thanks for this idea- you're right that the best way would be some kind of preloading array. the problem is that the number of images is huge-- 100,000 (basically I'm simulating a kind of stop motion film) so I can't put them all into that array. I may try to make some kind of dynamic loop where after each image is called it gets replaced by a new one from the directory so when it returns to that spot in the loop it actually displays an image further along in the sequence but not sure I have the coding chops to get that to work...